# How to debug files that was created by my app on Android

Tags: android

I have created an Android app that generates a `.json` file. When I print the path of generated file I see this:

```
/data/data/com.my_package.my_app/files/my_file.json
```

But using `Astro File Manager` or `ES File Explorer` I cannot find/access it. My phone is not rooted and I intentionally don't want to root. I wonder how can I see the file content for debugging purposes? (I understand that I can read the file in my app and print as a log message in the console, but is there a more civil method of doing this?)

Comment: try to generate and save your file in SD card. this will allow Astro File Manager or ES File Explorer to find/access it.

Comment: You could copy the file to external memory. Then other apps have access. You could also generate the file directly in external memory during a debug period. Use getExternalFilesdir() for that. Request write permission in manifest.